# How can I automatically add line breaks in a textarea?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea that isn't very wide. I want as the user enters text for there to be line break once a line has 50 characters. I don't want any wrapped text. Just line breaks. Is there a way to make this happen?

I tried to test something basic out on one line and failed.

```
$('#textarea').keypress(function (e) {
if ($(this).val().length == 50) {
    $(this).val()[51] == '\n'
}
})
```

I clearly am not very experienced. I don't know if I should start looking into the regExp object.

I can't allow wrapped text because I need to measure what each line of the textarea has. After the user has submitted the form, I need to be able to use something like this:

```
var line = $('#textarea').val().split('\n');
for(i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Of course. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: You should do this on the backend, and just visually wrap the text on the front end (which I think is default anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You have use `%` to see if the length and multiple of 50 and add \n at the end. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZE6W/1)

```
if ($(this).val().length % 50 == 0) {
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. But how can I get that to work for each line?

Comment: @Nubby, Updated my answer. You have use `%` to see if the length and multiple of 50 and add `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtPPk/2

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var length = $this.val().length;
    if(length % 50 == 0) {
        $this.val($this.val() + "\n");   
    }
});
```

Comment: This works too, but just not on the first line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('textarea').keypress(function () {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  if (length % 51 == 0 &&
      length > 0) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(val + '\n');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2QZbG/

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked great.